# Airflow failed slack message

Tags: slack, airflow

How can I configure Airflow so that any failure in the DAG will (immediately) result in a slack message?

At this moment I manage it by creating a slack_failed_task:

```py
slack_failed_task =  SlackAPIPostOperator(
    task_id='slack_failed',
    channel="#datalabs",
    trigger_rule='one_failed',
    token="...",
    text = ':red_circle: DAG Failed',
    icon_url = 'http://airbnb.io/img/projects/airflow3.png',
    dag=dag)
```

And set this task (one_failed) upstream from each other task in the DAG:

```py
slack_failed_task << download_task_a
slack_failed_task << download_task_b
slack_failed_task << process_task_c
slack_failed_task << process_task_d
slack_failed_task << other_task_e
```

It works, but it's error prone since forgetting to add the task will skip the slack notifications and seems like a lot of work.

Is there perhaps a way to expand on the `email_on_failure` property in the DAG?

Bonus ;-) for including a way to pass the name of the failed task to the message.

Comment: Hey Tom, I noticed at the bottom you put "Is there perhaps a way to expand on the `email_on_failure` property in the DAG?" - I do not know if you are still interested, but you may benefit from reading my post on how I have configured my airflow settings for emails on DAG failures using Amazon SES and the `email_on_failure` property. [SO Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645578/email-on-failure-using-aws-ses-in-apache-airflow-dag). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanted Slack messages to begin with :-) I thought the `email_on_failure` could be a `sink` to send messages to that then are either mailed or slacked or ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe this example will be helpful:

```
def slack_failed_task(contextDictionary, **kwargs):  
       failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
         task_id='slack_failed',
         channel="#datalabs",
         token="...",
         text = ':red_circle: DAG Failed',
         owner = '_owner',)
         return failed_alert.execute


task_with_failed_slack_alerts = PythonOperator(
task_id='task0',
python_callable=<file to execute>,
on_failure_callback=slack_failed_task,
provide_context=True,
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the new **SlackWebhookOperator** which is there in Airflow version>=1.10.0

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator

slack_msg="Hi Wssup?"

slack_test =  SlackWebhookOperator(
    task_id='slack_test',
    http_conn_id='slack_connection',
    webhook_token='/1234/abcd',
    message=slack_msg,
    channel='#airflow_updates',
    username='airflow_'+os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'],
    icon_emoji=None,
    link_names=False,
    dag=dag)
```

Note: Make sure you have `slack_connection` added in your Airflow connections as

```
host=https://hooks.slack.com/services/
```

Comment: It's been more than a year & at my previous job, so I cannot test it anytime soon, but thanks anyway for responding.

Comment: No problem. It might help others :)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I configure Airflow so that any failure in the DAG will
> (immediately) result in a slack message?

Using `airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack_webhook.SlackWebhookHook` you can achieve that, by passing a `on_failure_callback` function on DAG level.

> Bonus ;-) for including a way to pass the name of the failed task to
> the message.

```py
def fail():
    raise Exception("Task failed intentionally for testing purpose")

def success():
    print("success")

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    tis_dagrun = context['ti'].get_dagrun().get_task_instances()
    failed_tasks = []
    for ti in tis_dagrun:
        if ti.state == State.FAILED:
            # Adding log url
            failed_tasks.append(f"<{ti.log_url}|{ti.task_id}>")
    
    dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id
    exec_date=context.get('execution_date')

    blocks = [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":red_circle: Dag Failed."
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": f"section{uuid.uuid4()}",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": f"*Dag*: {dag} \n *Execution Time*: {exec_date}"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/main/airflow/www/static/pin_100.png",
                "alt_text": "Airflow"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": f"Failed Tasks: {', '.join(failed_tasks)}"
            }
        }
    ]
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookHook(
        http_conn_id='slack-airflow',
        channel="#airflow-notifications",    
        blocks=blocks,
        username='airflow'
    )
    failed_alert.execute()
    return 

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
}
with DAG(
    dag_id="slack-test",
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2021,8,19),
    schedule_interval=None,
    on_failure_callback=task_fail_slack_alert
) as dag:

    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test",
        python_callable=fail
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test2",
        python_callable=success
    )
```

[image: Slack Message Preview]

Answer (score 3):

The BaseOperator supports 'on_failure_callback' parameter:

> on_failure_callback (callable) – a function to be called when a task instance of this task fails. a context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function. Context contains references to related objects to the task instance and is documented under the macros section of the API.

I have not tested this but you should be able to define a function which posts to slack on failure and pass it to each task definition. To get the name of the current task, you can use the {{ task_id }} template.

Comment: I couldn't get the `{{ task_id }}` to work yet, but your help was appreciated

Comment: It's also the issue I'm having. I can get variables directly from `context` var, but I templating such as `{{ task_id }}` does not work

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to add the callback to the DAG and to be inhered by all its tasks:

```
def on_failure_callback(context):
    webhook_url = os.getenv('SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN')
    slack_data = {
        'text': "@here DAG {} Failed".format(context['dag'].dag_id)
    }

    response = requests.post(
        webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_data),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_with_templated_dir',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    on_failure_callback=on_failure_callback
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can [send an email to a slack channel](https://slack.com/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack#:%7E:text=From%20your%20desktop%2C%20open%20the,channel%5D%20or%20%5Bconversation%5D.). This way, you don't need any additional setup, and you can give an array of emails, one for the real email setup, and one for the slack channel.

```
'email': ["realemail@gmail.com", "slackchannelname@company.slack.com"]
```