# Apache airflow sla miss - does not send email

Tags: airflow

I use Apache Airflow and I wanted it to send me an email when there is an sla miss. Here is my configuration [Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHymP.png)

I created a dag run that misses sla for sure.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
    , 'depends_on_past': False
    , 'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 17, 0, 0)
    , 'retries': 0
    , 'sla': timedelta(seconds=15)
    , 'email': ['myemail@myemail.com']
    , 'email_on_failure': True
    , 'email_on_retry': True
}

dag = DAG('sla-email-test'
          , default_args=args
          , max_active_runs=1
          , schedule_interval="@daily")

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='timeout',
    bash_command='sleep 60',
    retries=0,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Unfortunetely it did not send any email
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWPh.png)

What can be a cause, can I use the gui to see logs about it ?

Comment: How is your servers mail component configured since you are using `localhost`?

Comment: I would try a different SMTP server to rule out an issue with a local one. You can use gmail or signup for a free mailgun account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using local sendmail, change your airflow config match the one below. You should not need smtp_user or smtp_password.

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = False
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
#smtp_user = not used
#smtp_password = not used
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from =  SendingAlias@Company.com
```

You can tail the airflow worker to see if it attempts to send the email by using the command: `journalctl -u airflow-worker -f`

You can also see your sendmail logs by using: `cat /var/log/maillog`.

This should solve your problem / give you enough information to debug.

Here is my write up on how we handled this problem when we ran into it: [airflow email on failure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645578/email-on-failure-using-aws-ses-in-apache-airflow-dag)