# Where to find Airflows email logs?

Tags: smtp, airflow

I'm setting up Airflows build in STMP email configuration in an Airflow instance deployed in Kubernetes. I've been able to see logs from the email server that indicate I am successfully logging in but I'm not getting emails when my DAG's are successful. I have `'email_on_success': True` set in my DAG.

I'm not sure if or where I could find logs of where airflow is trying to send out these emails. I've checked on the webserver, scheduler, and worker pod logs but don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is the airflow worker that services the email features. You can do `journalctl –u airflow-worker –f` to monitor it during a Dag run and see if it is attempting to send an email on success.

If you are using sendmail, you can check it's logs by doing `cat /var/log/maillog`.

I had a problem like yours last year, but with `email_on_failure`. My write up is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645578/email-on-failure-using-aws-ses-in-apache-airflow-dag) if it helps!