# Airflow - Email Notification not working with SES

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have created two Dag's to check the email configuration for Airflow.
Basically I want to get an email alert whenever a job is failed.
I have also gone through the following links but unfortunately, I am not able to resolve the problem.

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645578/email-on-failure-using-aws-ses-in-apache-airflow-dag)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541801/where-to-find-airflows-email-logs)

**DAG One: ( Success Job )**

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['firstnamelastname@company.com','firstnamelastname@company.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'email_on_success': True
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

dag = DAG('success', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',default_args=default_args,
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

**DAG Two : ( Failed Job )**

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['firstnamelastname@company.com','firstnamelastname@company.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'email_on_success': True
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


def print_hello():
    xxxx
    return 'Hello world!'

dag = DAG('success', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',default_args=default_args,
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

I was expecting to get an email for both of the jobs. Since both of the Jobs contains configuration for **email_on_success** and **email_on_failure**
But I did not receive any email.

Please have a look at the Job Run Stats :

[image]

[image]

Here is my **SMTP Configuration** under airflow.cfg :

```
smtp_host = email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
smtp_user = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
smtp_password = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = firstnamelastname@company.com
```

I have obtained the username and password from the `Create My SMTP Credentials` under the SES Service. I also have a verified email address. Security Group for my EC2 contains all outbound traffic for all protocol, all port and for destination `0.0.0.0/0`

What else I am missing here?
Is it possible to configure/generate logs for the email sending process?

Comment: I can tell you that we are using the same airflow.cfg as you, and it is working fine with us. Your code also looks fine to me. Are you getting any error from the failed task logs? or from the scheduler sdtout?

Comment: I have started receiving the notification for my other jobs. I don't know what is the exact issue. For some jobs, it is sending the notification for some job it is not.

Comment: I had this exact same issue. Here's my write up / answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645578/email-on-failure-using-aws-ses-in-apache-airflow-dag.

Comment: @Zack The first link points to your solution itself. I have followed that. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. But still, I am not able to understand the root cause. I mean why it is happening so.