# Airflow on_failure_callback & SlackAPIPostOperator

Tags: slack, airflow

Trying to post to Slack using the on_failure_callback. I have this procedure below and my default dag args has

```
'on_failure_callback' : notify_slack_failure
```

When my task fails, it is creating the output in /tmp..but my Slack message is not posting.  When I test it via command line it will post to Slack. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

```py
    def notify_slack_failure(context):
       """
       Define the callback to post on Slack if a failure is detected in the Workflow
       :return: operator.execute
       """
       
       cmd = "echo '" + getSlackToken() +"' > /tmp/a.out"
       os.system("touch /tmp/b.out")
       os.system(cmd)
       text_message='333'
       #text_message=str(context['task_instance'])
       
       operator = SlackAPIPostOperator(
          task_id='failure',
          text=text_message,
          token=getSlackToken(),
          channel=SLACK_CHANNEL,
          username=SLACK_USER
       )
       os.system("touch /tmp/e1.out")
       return operator.execute(context=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

George -Welcome to SO! Try running this code. See if Airflow is able to post to Slack, and if the code writing to the tmp file was messing it up.

```
def notify_slack_failure(contextDictionary, **kwargs):  
   """
   Define the callback to post on Slack if a failure is detected in the Workflow
   :return: operator.execute
   """
   text_message='333'
   #text_message=str(context['task_instance'])

   operator= SlackAPIPostOperator(
      task_id='failure',
      token=getSlackToken(),
      text=text_message,
      channel=SLACK_CHANNEL,
      username=SLACK_USER,)
      return operator.execute
```

Taken from [SO Slack Airflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586356/airflow-failed-slack-message?rq=1)

Comment: thank you so much..but the error was mine.  we go through a http proxy for our outbound connections. Have it set in the bash profile...but forgot to define it for the systemd service.  1st time up..and dumb mistake. Sorry!

Comment: No worries George!

Answer (score 0):

In the command line I had my `http_proxy` vars defined and did not have them set for the daemon processes.